# Azure data share - '\N' in output instead of NULL

Tags: azure-data-share

We have a set of SQL views that are being shared via Azure Data Share.  We share this with an outside organization.  They have reported that instances of NULL are being replaced by '\N'.  I see nothing in the share settings that would cause this, and the SQL tables with the source data return NULL, not '\N'.  Is there something in Data Share that does this replacement?  It seems to me that this is a very simple thing to address on the receiving end, and I've received no clear explanation why it can't be done, but I have to check into this and am at a loss.  I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: DuckDuckGo found me this answer -- did you try to search first? https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7247

Comment: I did, and I shared a similar page simply to convince them that it's a synonym for NULL.  Fwiw, the source SQL is Azure SQL, not MySQL, but the same concept applies.  I'm just hoping that some Azure wizard either (1) knows how Data Share might be making such a replacement, or (2) can show that it does not do that replacement.